# How can I know that a cron job has started or finished?

Tags: linux, cron

I have put a long running python program in a cron job on a server, so that I can turn off my computer without interrupting the job.
Now I would like to know if the job is correctly started, if it has finished, if there are reasons to stop at a certain point, and so on. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not get that `cron` job to have a log file. Also just do a `ps` before shutdown.

Comment: The PS shows the job, it is sufficient for what I needed. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

You could have it write to a logfile, but as it sounds like this isn't possible, you could probably have cron email you the output of the job, try adding `MAILTO=you@example.com` to your crontab. You should also find evidence of cron activity in your system logfiles (try `grep cron /var/log/*` to find likely logs on your system).

If you are using cron simply as a way to run processes after you disconnect from a server, consider using [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/):

- type `screen` and press return
- set your script running
- type `Ctrl+A Ctrl+D` to detatch from the screen

The process continues running even if you log off. Later on simply

- `screen -r`

And you will be will reattached, allowing you to review the script's output

Comment: Thank you, I know this. But when a job is started without a log file, without using screen, how do I do ?